# How can I watch something for a change in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to set up a clipboard watcher.  In most languages, the usual path for this is something like:

```
func main() {
  old_contents
  loop {
    new = get_clipboard()
    if new != old_contents {
      old_contents = new
      do_something
    }
  }
```

This doesn't immediately work in Rust, because loops get their own version of variables and such.  Just in a general sense, how should I be going about this?

Comment: I notice your loop never terminates so `old_contents` is never used outside the `loop`. Is that relevant?

Comment: What do you mean by "their own version of variables and such"?

Comment: I think you should read [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book) to understand and learn the language Rust properly. Loops will be explained there as well and it might help you to avoid some sciolism about Rust. Please read it :)

Comment: @Schwern It's used inside the loop, which is the sole point - I really just want it to watch for a change each loop and do something if it changes.

Comment: @HaroldSchreckengost Your example isn't Rust, but the basic idea will work. `let mut new = 42; let mut old_contents = value; loop { ... }` What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

> *because loops get their own version of variables and such*

This is not so for a simple `loop`. Here's a demo.

```
fn main() {
    let mut outer = 42;

    loop {
        println!("Outer in loop: {}", outer);
        outer = 23;
        break;
    }

    println!("Outer after loop: {}", outer);
}
```

Alternatively, you can [return a value from a loop](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-05-control-flow.html#returning-values-from-loops).

```
fn main() {
    let outer = loop {
        println!("In the loop.");
        break 23;
    };

    println!("Outer after loop: {}", outer);
}
```

Comment: *"This is not so for a simple loop"*: this is not true for every construct in Rust. Rust has no implicit variables somwhere declared.